# How to match a regex 1 to 3 times in a sed command?

Tags: regex, sed

## Problem

I want to get any text that consists of **1 to three digits followed by a %** but without the *%* using **sed**.

## What I tried

So i guess the following regex should match the right pattern : `[0-9]{1,3}%`. 
Then i can use this sed command to catch the three digits and only print them : 
`sed -nE 's/.*([0-9]{1,3})%.*/\1/p'`

## Example

However when i run it, it shows :

```
$ echo "100%" | sed -nE 's/.*([0-9]{1,3})%.*/\1/p'
0
```

instead of

```
100
```

Obviously, there's something wrong with my sed command and i think the problem comes from here :

```
[0-9]{1,3}
```

which apparently doesn't do what i want it to do.

edit:

## Solution

The `.*` at the start of `sed -nE 's/.*([0-9]{1,3})%.*/\1/p'` "ate" the two first digits.

The right way to write it, according to Wicktor's answer, is :

```
sed -nE 's/(.*[^0-9])?([0-9]{1,3})%.*/\2/p'
```

Comment: hint: `.*` is greedy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.*` grabs all digits leaving just the last of the three digits in `100%`.

Use

```
sed -nE 's/(.*[^0-9])?([0-9]{1,3})%.*/\2/p'
```

**Details**

- `(.*[^0-9])?` - (Group 1) an optional sequence of any 0 or more chars up to the non-digit char including it
- `([0-9]{1,3})` - (Group 2) one to three digits
- `%` - a `%` char
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

The match is replaced with Group 2 contents, and that is the only value `p`rinted since `n` suppresses the default line output.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, however why did mine catch only 1 digit ? Is it because i forgot the `[^0-9]` part so the `.*` at the start of the regex "ate" the 2 first digits ?

Comment: @matt *The `.*` grabs all digits leaving just the last of the three digits in `100%`* `.*` is *greedy*.

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier to use a `cut + grep` option:

```
echo "abc 100%" | cut -d% -f1 | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}'
100

echo "100%" | cut -d% -f1 | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}'
100
```

Or else you may use this `awk`:

```
echo "100%" | awk 'match($0, /[0-9]{1,3}%/){print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH-1)}'
100
```

Or else if you have `gnu grep` then use `-P` (PCRE) option:

```
echo "abc 100%" | ggrep -oP '[0-9]{1,3}(?=%)'
100
```

Comment: Thanks I respect your comment. I try to offer an alternative only when I think (and I may be wrong in my interpretation) original tool or method is not the best way to solve the stated problem and there are better alternatives.

Comment: I selected the Wiktor's answer because it uses only the sed command with the `-E` option so it is portable, but thanks to you i discovered the `cut` command which is interesting because it is much simpler than `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/.*\<([0-9]{1,3})%.*/\1/p' file
```

This is a filtering exercise, so use the `-n` option.

Use a back reference to capture 1 to 3 digits, followed by  `%` and print the  result if successful.

N.B. The `\<` ensures the digits start on a word boundary, `\b` could also be used. The `-E` option is employed to reduce the number of back slashes which would normally be necessary to quote `(`,`)`,`{` and `}` metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

Came here during my search for a similar item: A large number of files had to have their last numbers (including underscore) removed, one and two digits. Like `example_10.mp3` into `example.mp3`. I spare everyone all my efforts, read some twenty pages, and also tried all `+` and `*` and `?` combination, in front and behind, with and without parenthesis. Of course, also the one mentioned above: `[0-9]{1,2}`, which can be found in many places, and doesn't work.
In the end, the solution was `/_+([0-9]).mp3/.mp3`.

I also tried for your description:

```
$ t=aaa234%bbbbb
$ echo "$t" "${t/+([0-9])%/}"
aaa234%bbbbb aaabbbbb

$ t=aaa2%bbbbb
$ echo "$t" "${t/+([0-9])%/}"
aaa2%bbbbb aaabbbbb
```

I think, this is the one you were looking for?